# How to resize button content in WPF with a viewbox while maintaining the Font size?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am creating an app and I need the content of a button to be resizable when the user minimises their screen. We know that the viewbox does this in WPF; it's the easiest way to resize text automatically.

This is the code for [the top part] of the button, I apologise about the formatting:

```
 <Button Grid.Row="0"
Grid.Column="2"
                                Background="#3767B0"
                                Style="{DynamicResource IconStyle}"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                       <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate >
                                        <Viewbox>
                                            <TextBlock>&#xE90A;</TextBlock>
                                            </Viewbox>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Button.ContentTemplate>

                         
                                </Button>
```

What I want to get out of this is: to use the Viewbox in WPF to resize the content of this button while maintaining the font size of the content.

This resizes the content of the button, but the button's content is not maintained:

[image]

This is how it should look like with a viewbox, and should resize properly:

[image]

By maintaining I mean I want to use the viewbox whilst the content of the button (which is a child of the viewbox) looks exactly how it would've with a font size of 22. You can see how I want it to look like with a viewbox inside the content of the button in the image above. I've tried to be as clear as possible on this. Maybe I don't understand how the viewbox works?

Someone requested the icon style. Here is the icon style code:

```
  <Style TargetType="Button"
               x:Key="IconStyle"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily"
                    Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets" />

            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan"
                    Value="2" />

            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="0,0,0,60" />

            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="White" />

            <Setter Property="FontSize"
                    Value="80" />

            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="#307A85" />

            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />

            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="0" />


            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="15"
                                      ShadowDepth="0"
                                      Opacity="0.4"
                                      Color="Black" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

Comment: The bounty might attract more attention. But you know what would really improve your chances of getting a good answer, or any answer at all? Clean up your question so that it includes a good [mcve], a clear explanation of what that code does now, what it is you want it to do instead, and what specifically you need help with. Since you are dealing with layout issues, it would be especially helpful if you could provide a clear illustration of what the "bad" and "good" output looks like. I have read your question three times already and still don't really know what you are asking.

Comment: OK sir I have edited this may you have another look at it Peter my friend?

Comment: What is the style `IconStyle`, is it possible to post on the question?

Comment: You really should read [mcve]. Also, you would likely find [ask] helpful, especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: For what it's worth, other than the lack of a decent code example, I _think_ you are getting closer to a clearer question. But I still don't know what you mean when you use the word "maintained". For example, you say you want to _"resize the content"_ and then immediately after say you want _"maintaining the size of the content"_. Those seem like contradictory statements to me. Clearly you don't intend that, but I'm unable to infer what you _do_ actually mean. Maybe you can show two different sizes as they would appear correctly, but where the difference is size is still clear?

Comment: Peter Dun, my friend, as you can see I have tried my best to make this question shorter and clearer I will have a read of this but maybe it's because you can't find a solution to it.

Comment: Hello Peter by maintained I want the content of the button to look as how it would've looked like with a font size of 22 (inside of a viewbox)?

Comment: It's unclear what that is supposed to mean. You probably just want to have some margin around the TextBlock? Then set its Margin property.

Comment: Hey Clemens, don't really understand what's 'not clear' about my question?

Comment: If you think my question is not clear feel free to downvote it OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you need to implement, then remove the ViewBox and set the explicit dimensions of the TextBlock.
I am showing an arbitrary example, but for your task, you yourself choose the required dimensions and alignment.

```
    <Button Background="#3767B0"
            Style="{DynamicResource IconStyle}"
            BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <Button.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock Width="300"
                           Height="300"
                           FontSize="200"
                           Text="&#xE90A;"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Button.ContentTemplate>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Most likely, will suit you  the variant without Width and Height only with FontSize.

Comment: Hello Eld you are the closest to the question so I will give you the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

Hello my good friends on Stack OverFlow. I have found a solution to this problem, all I had to do was set the padding of the TextBlock:

```
  <!--FEEDBACK BUTTON-->
                    <Button Grid.Row="3"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            BorderThickness="3"
                            Name="Feedback_Button"
                            BorderBrush="White"
                            Click="Button_Click"
                            MouseEnter="Button_MouseEnter"
                            MouseLeave="Button_MouseLeave">

                        <Button.Template>
                        
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>

                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="218*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="68*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        

                      

                        <Button Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Background="#3767B0"
                                FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                Foreground="White"
                                Content="Feedback"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent">

                            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Viewbox>
                                        <TextBlock Padding="15">&#xE90A;</TextBlock>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Button.ContentTemplate>
                        </Button>

                        <Button Grid.Row="4"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Background="#FF2D5BA0"
                                FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextButton}"
                                Content="Feedback"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent">

                            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Viewbox>
                                        <TextBlock Padding="15">Feedback</TextBlock>
                                    </Viewbox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Button.ContentTemplate>
                        </Button>



                    </Grid>

                    </Button>
                    <!--FEEDBACK BUTTON-->
```

Thank you my friends for your help, such a simple solution I would've expected you guys to know this.

Cheers,

Comment: The Padding property resizes the allocated space for a nested element.
In this case, for Text.
But the space will change when the outer container is resized.
A constant distance will be maintained between the outer container and the nested element.
This is the same as <TextBlock Margin = "15" ...>.
If you need to maintain a constant size of the TextBlock itself, you must either set the ViewBox to a constant size, or delete it and set the TextBlock to a constant size.

Comment: Hello EldHasp - I do not necessarily agree with what you're saying. I've done testing with this and putting a value for the padding makes the box resize perfectly. The 'Margin' property does not fix my problem but make it worse. Setting the ViewBox to a constant size does not solve the problem so I'm wondering if you have a gap of knowledge in how the viewbox works?

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Joney , I do not quite clearly understand what you need to implement, so I cannot give an exact answer.

General answer for using different layout.

1. The ViewBox scales the content to the maximum allowed size provided by the outer container.
   The Padding property of a container sets the size of the border between the container and its contents.
   The element's Margin property sets the size of the border between the element and its containing container.
   That is, these are very close properties.
   In our case, the main content is Text.
   Therefore, there is no difference how to set the size of the border: between the Text and the containing TextBlock (TextBlock.Padding) or between the TextBlock and its containing outer container (the Grid line).

Look at two examples in which I set the background colors for better clarity.

Example with Padding

```
<Window x:Class="ViewBoxScaleText.PaddingWind"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewBoxScaleText"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="PaddingWind" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="LightGreen">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Padding="15"
                           Background="LightBlue"
                           Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Text="Feedback"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Example with Margin

```
<Window x:Class="ViewBoxScaleText.MarginWind"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewBoxScaleText"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MarginWind" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="LightGreen">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Margin="15"
                           Background="LightBlue"
                           Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tb}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
        <TextBox x:Name="tb" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Text="Feedback"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The color of the regions shows that the containers have different sizes, but this does not affect the location and size of the Text.
Try to enter text in the field at the bottom of the window to see how the amount of text affects its size and the size of the border.

2. Since the ViewBox scales the entire content, both the text size size and are the border scaled.
   If in the examples above you change the size of the window, you will see that the size of the container occupied by the text also changes.
   This happens due to the fact that the setting of the border occurs inside the ViewBox and thus we set the size of the border, in fact, in units relative to the size of the text.
   Changing the size of the text will change the size of the face and therefore change the overall container for the text.

Here is an example with the ability to change the font size in the very bottom margin of the window.
See how this affects the size of the border.

```
<Window x:Class="ViewBoxScaleText.FontSizeWind"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewBoxScaleText"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FontSizeWind" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Background="LightGreen">
            <Viewbox>
                <TextBlock Margin="15"
                           Background="LightBlue"
                           Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbText}" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbFontSize}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Border>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbText" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Text="Feedback"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbFontSize" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Text="80"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

3. Here are some more layout options in one XAML so that you can launch, check their behavior and choose the one that suits you

```
    <Window x:Class="ViewBoxScaleText.MultiVariantWind"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewBoxScaleText"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MultiVariantWind" Height="750" Width="400">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Background="LightGreen" Margin="5">
                <Viewbox>
                    <TextBlock Margin="15"
                                   Background="LightBlue"
                                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbText}" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbFontSize}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="LightGreen" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">
                <Viewbox Margin="15">
                    <TextBlock
                                   Background="LightBlue"
                                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbText}" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbFontSize}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="LightGreen" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2">
                <Viewbox Width="150" Height="150">
                    <TextBlock
                                   Background="LightBlue"
                                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbText}" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbFontSize}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Border>
            <Border Background="LightGreen" Margin="5" Grid.Row="3">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="70*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock
                                   Background="LightBlue"
                                   Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbText}" FontSize="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbFontSize}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbText" Grid.Row="4" Margin="10" Text="Feedback"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tbFontSize" Grid.Row="5" Margin="10" Text="80"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: For some reason, the last example is not fully displayed here.
But when you go into editing the answer - all the code is there.
Maybe it's just me.
If you also do not see the code in full, then write - I will post it again.